# Tomcat: square brackets in logger name

Tags: tomcat, log4j

In the Tomcat `log4j.properties` file I see this loggers:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]=INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]=INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

Why are square brackets in logger name? What does it mean?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, which is for _programming_ questions.  Your question belongs on [sf] or [webmasters.se]

Comment: Ok. What can  I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply tomcat's log layout :

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[${engine}].[${host}].[${context}]
```

no any special meaning. for more see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html